# MSAccess Barcode leading zeros

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I am just testing something out. I am trying to build a tracking information tracker. I am also pretty new to MS Access.

```
Private Sub btn_Submit_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute _
    "INSERT INTO TrackNum_Table(TrackingNum_TrackNum) " & _
    "VALUES ('" & Me.txt_Track.Value & "')"
```

So far it is just a text box to see if this works. The scanning works. UPS labels have alphanumeric tracking and the Fedex labels just have numbers, but when scanned they have leading zeros.

I am looking to store the scanned numbers through a submit button for now, but will try to integrate auto logging when scanned.

When I scan to the textbox, I want to remove the leading zeros before I press the submit button.

Any assistance will be helpful!

Comment: Is it possible the UPS tracking could start with zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want InStr() and Mid().

Before you do `CurrentDb.Execute`

```
Dim strIn As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim iLen As Integer

strIn = Me.txt_Track.Value

iLen = Len(strIn)

For i = 1 To iLen
    If InStr(strIn, "0") = 1 Then 'by default checks the first char.
        strIn = Mid(strIn, 2)     'strIn now starts at the 2nd char.
    End If
Next i

...insert into...values...strIn
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much for your assistance! Do you have any idea how I could tell whether it is a fedex label vs. a ups label and submit it within the Insert Into.... values.. strIn.. area as well. If I added a column say, "Type_TrackNum"

Comment: Please start a new question. Also it could be important to know if it's possible that the UPS tracking could start with zeros and if you need those removed too.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler, alternate approach to the one shared by wazz is the following:

```
Private Sub btn_Submit_Click()
Dim str As String
If IsNumeric(Me.txt_Track.Value) Then
    str = Int(Me.txt_Track.Value)
Else
    str = Me.txt_Track.Value
End If
CurrentDb.Execute _
    "INSERT INTO TrackNum_Table(TrackingNum_TrackNum) " & _
    "VALUES ('" & str & "')"
```

This removes any leading zeroes and decimals from the field if it's numeric, and since only the FedEx labels are numeric, it doesn't affect the UPS ones.

Comment: Snap. I started playing with IsNumeric but didn't know Int would do that.

Comment: Actually, i was just playing with this and when i threw a letter into the mix  i got a type mismatch on `Int(Me.txt_Track.Value)`, so you have to make sure this only accepts numbers.

Comment: Yes, that's true, and that's where the `IIF(IsNumeric(` comes in. If you throw in a number, that should return false, and the leading zeroes won't be removed. As I understood the question, that's partly the objective. Only the numeric (FedEx) codes need the leading numbers removed.

Comment: I'm using what you wrote, with IsNumeric. It's as if each part of the IIf is evaluated separately. The 2nd part fails and trips an err even with isnumeric. ... i'm passing in a string.

Comment: Oh, yes, silly of me. VBA tends to have trouble with IIFs. This works fine in SQL. I'll rewrite it to a normal if.

Comment: Right. IIf was so clean, too bad about that. I just checked this and... just for clarity, if an alphanumeric is passed in that happens to start with zeros, the zeros won't be removed.